# How to get total CPU time for java process using MBean

Tags: java, profiling, mbeans

I am looking for a cross platform/vendor solution to get total CPU time used by a java process thus far (not at the moment) using MBeans. I did stumble upon some suggestions to use `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean::getProcessCpuTime()`. I have couple of issues with it.

1. Oracle strongly discourages to use classes in `com.sun` package
2. This will work only for vendor Oracle.
3. This doesn't work on Windows

Another suggested solution is to `ThreadMXBean` to add CPU times for all live threads. This however will give me CPU usage time only for live threads. If there were threads created and destroyed in between two calls to compute CPU times, I would be looking at wrong numbers as this method would capture CPU usage of threads that are no longer live.

Comment: Where does it say that it doesn't work on Windows?